# dispatching ClipboardEvent on textarea element does not work

Tags: javascript, events, dispatchevent, html5-clipboard-api

I wont to simulate paste event trough javascript as shown on snipped below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-9 col-lg-8 form-field input_controls">
       <textarea rows="8"cols="60" id="short_description" name="short_description"></textarea>
    </div>


    <script>
    const transfer = new window.DataTransfer();
    transfer.setData('text/plain', 'I LOVE YOU');

    const element = document.querySelector('[name="short_description"]');
    element.dispatchEvent(new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        clipboardData: transfer
    }));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I get no text filled on the `textarea` above? Any idea why this does not work?